# Why do scp'ed files disappear?

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm doing a simple scp to a Home Assistant server on a Raspi. I've done this a million times on other servers and I've never had this happening.

From my local machine I scp a file:

```
$ scp local_file.txt  hassio@homeassistant.local:~/
local_file.txt                               100% 1392   286.4KB/s   00:00
```

As you can see the file appears to be successfully transferred. When I check out the home folder on the remote however, the file is not there:

```
$ ssh hassio@homeassistant.local
| |  | |                          /\           (_)   | |            | |  
| |__| | ___  _ __ ___   ___     /  \   ___ ___ _ ___| |_ __ _ _ __ | |_ 
|  __  |/ _ \| '_ \ _ \ / _ \   / /\ \ / __/ __| / __| __/ _\ | '_ \| __|
| |  | | (_) | | | | | |  __/  / ____ \\__ \__ \ \__ \ || (_| | | | | |_ 
|_|  |_|\___/|_| |_| |_|\___| /_/    \_\___/___/_|___/\__\__,_|_| |_|\__|

Welcome to the Home Assistant command line.
[...some more welcome output here...]
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ ls -l 
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jun  7 14:08 addons -> /addons
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jun  7 14:08 backup -> /backup
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jun  7 14:08 config -> /config
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             6 Jun  7 14:08 media -> /media
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             6 Jun  7 14:08 share -> /share
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             4 Jun  7 14:08 ssl -> /ssl
```

`~` is in this case `/root`:

```
➜  ~ pwd
/root
```

So you might think that the user hassio has no rights to write files there, but I can easily create a file when I'm ssh'ed into it:

```
➜  ~ echo "hello" > a_new_file.txt
➜  ~ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             6 Jun  7 18:56 a_new_file.txt
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jun  7 14:08 addons -> /addons
[etc..]
```

What might be happening here?

Comment: Maybe instead of scping to "~/" try doing "/root/", or if that doesn't work try making a new folder with "777" permissions and see if that helps. If none of that works, try a priest

Comment: [scp transfers file successfully into host machine but file won't show up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441061/scp-transfers-file-successfully-into-host-machine-but-file-wont-show-up)

Comment: You have to escape the `~`, so that the remote shell can expand it as expected. `scp ... hassio@...:\~/`.

Comment: Make sure that homeassistant.local actually resolves to the machine you think it does. If you're doing the scp from one machine and the ssh from a different one, it's possible that your `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/hosts` or even your network's DNS settings are resulting in it being copied to an unexpected machine.